# I can use Apollo Client without Apollo Server? I have a plain GraphQl express server and want to integrate with front-end ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have a working backend with GraphQl and express on NodeJs.

I want to communicate the back-end with the front-end (ReactJS), to do this I want to use Apollo Client.
So I have to change my backend too? Or just the Apollo Client?

If I don't have to use Apollo Server to use Apollo Client, there is a advantage to use the two of them?

Comment: You don't need to use Apollo server according to the [FAQ](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/resources/faq/) though they do recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of [persisted queries](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-persisted-queries) if you use both Apollo Server and Apollo Client. Future features like `@live`, `@stream` and `@defer` directives may require using both as well. Generally speaking, though, any standard GraphQL client can make requests to any GraphQL server, as long as the server doesn't somehow deviate from the [spec](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018).